# SQL - Main drive full - Added another data file - not working!

Tags: sql-server

Our SQL server has run out of space on the C:\ drive.
There is around 20gb space free on the G:\ drives (currently mainly used for Log files)

I created a Data File on the G:\ drive, on the same file group as the large file which is on the C:\ drive.

I still get errors saying the data file is full etc...

Have i missed something?

(this is a SQL 2000 database - i'm using Management Studio from my workstation however)

Please see screenshot to show layout of files:
http://twitpic.com/wnjl1/full

Answer (score 4):

Have you changed the properties on the original data file so it will no longer try to automatically grow (the default)?

Update : now away from my filtered work network, I can see the pic and indeed you've left the original file to grow automatically. Turn off the 1% growth on the Navision4_1_Data file and it should start using the file you've placed on G exclusively. You also have your PRIMARY file Navision4_Data on C and set to automatically grow.

What you have is a short term fix, but you should make it a priority to move all your data files off onto a separate disk altogether (and not the one with your transaction logs on). I also see that Navision4_Log3 is over 45GB - I'm guessing you're not doing regular backups of your database.

Comment: ^-This.  If you're not backing up your database, you're just asking for trouble.  If you're not interested in protecting the data, at least create a maintenance routine to clean up the logs.

Comment: we are doing regular backups... however they are not effective i don't think (set up by someone else)

What should i be looking for?

Comment: How are they setup? You should be having maintenance plans to backup up the database and transaction logs (when this is done the log will shrink to almost nothing, and gradually grow until it's time for the next backup), as well as a process in place for keeping backups somewhere away from the server. I think the default maintenance plan settings are for a database backup once a week and a transaction log backup every day, and this would ordinarily prevent a transaction log reaching the size you have unless you have millions of changes a day.